# Boost Gzip filters: compile failes

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to compile example from Boost Gzip filters page:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("hello.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
}
```

Sadly my g++ returns errors:

```
gzlib.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
gzlib.cpp:12:3: error: ‘filtering_streambuf’ was not declared in this scope
gzlib.cpp:12:23: error: ‘input’ was not declared in this scope
gzlib.cpp:12:30: error: ‘in’ was not declared in this scope
gzlib.cpp:13:29: error: ‘gzip_decompressor’ was not declared in this scope
```

What's wrong with this function and how to modify it to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Link to Boost Gzip filters: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the namespace in which to look up `filtering_streambuf`, `input`, or `gzip_decompressor`.
Try:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::iostreams;
    ifstream file("hello.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    copy(in, cout);
}
```

---

The reason that the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#examples) does not do this is because of the convention established in the [introduction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/):

> All classes, functions and templates introduced in the documentation are in the namespace boost::iostreams, unless otherwise indicated. Namespace qualification is usually omitted.

Comment: There is a lot of errors, so I've put output to pastebin. May be my Boost works incorrect? http://pastebin.com/fG2ZqpaJ

Comment: @ghostmansd: As mentioned [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#installation), you need to link to `zlib` for this to work. `zlib` is external to `boost`, but it is usually pre-installed on UNIX systems, and can otherwise be downloaded from [here](http://zlib.net/).

Comment: I compile using -lz, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @ghostmansd: You need to link to the `boost_iostreams` binary as well.